# Looking for a way to make this triangle at top of div rounded like this picture?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

Im trying to round this triangle on top of my div right now it is a regular triangle without curved sides here is my code.

```css
.info-panel {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #f4efe8 !important;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #f4efe8 !important
}

.info-panel:before,
.info-panel:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.info-panel:before {
  left: 39em;
  border: 11px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #f4efe8 !important;
}

.info-panel:after {
  left: 39em;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #f4efe8 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-panel">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+css+rounded+triangle&tbm=isch) of [How to achieve curved top pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58206983/4642212).